# Counterexample request: ill-scoped metavariable solution

Tags: dependent-type, type-inference

This is a question on metavariable (aka holes) resolution in (dependent) type theories.

In many referential implementations (such as Andras Kovacs' [elaboration-zoo](https://github.com/AndrasKovacs/elaboration-zoo/blob/d38b695d5177352501463fab2ac6d0929ba4472b/03-holes/Main.hs#L440-L442)), there is one step called 'scope check', which checks if the solution of a metavariable is well-scoped. It is unclear to me how a solution can be ill-scoped. I wonder if there is a counterexample showing an ill-scoped solution to a metavariable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I just came up with one. The following code block is written in a syntax similar to Agda.

```
test : (a : _) (B : Set) (b : B) -> a ≡ b
test a B b = refl
```

Assuming `≡` to be the homogeneous equality type and `refl` to be its constructor, the solution to the underscore is `B`, which is not defined there yet. Type checking the above code (with `open import Agda.Builtin.Equality`) will result in the following error message:

```
Cannot instantiate the metavariable _1 to solution B
since it contains the variable B
which is not in scope of the metavariable
when checking that the expression b has type _1
```